# How can I render light being reflected on a surface but keep the surface invisible?

Tags: compositing-nodes

I have an object which is catching and reflecting light from an emitter.

I want to keep the light but remove the object.

In the attached image I want to keep the main circular object in the middle but remove the background object - however I want to keep the light that is being reflected on it.

I have created render layers to seperate the items and render them individually but I can't figure out how to do this.

Any ideas please?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: See http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/58280#58280 or http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image/53360#53360 If you want the object to become invisible replace the secnd shader by a *Transparency* shader or similar

Comment: Thanks - still working on this - I haven't figured it out yet but I'm getting closer.

Comment: So you want to isolate the emission passes? Try checking out some tutorials on render passes.