# Best Way of Emitting Light from Image?

Tags: light, lighting

I thought making some light from television, it´s working but i don´t know, maybe has a better way.

[image]

Comment: What is your current method not doing that you would like it to do?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/53456/1853

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig