# Making an emission shader which does NOT cast light

Tags: materials, light

So i tried gooogling and asking around in discord servers but no one is really helping nor understanding what I need.

To sum it up, I need an object to LOOK like the sun in 3d space, aka it needs to be very bright. "just put an emission shader on it duh!" well there's a problem! I have cell shading and the size of the object depends on how smooth the shadow is! So if I have one light source which is huge, casting a very huge smooth shading all over my cell shaded objects, it just looks weird.

So - a fake glowing object. I just need an object that looks like its glowing but does not cast a shadow. That's all.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Making an Emission shader emit a different colour of light than the colour assigned to the object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's easily solved. Find a tab in the emitter's Object Properties called "Cycles Settings".

There's a bunch of things there that you can tell Cycles not to do when it munches through the object. The interesting checkbox in this case is : Diffuse. That tells cycles: ignore diffuse reflection rays for this object.

[image: is a noglo]

Comment: I didn't even know those exist haha, thank you!

Comment: I use this hellish abomination of a beloved monster software since 2000 and I definitely don't know everything. They just keep adding stuff. It never ends.