# AgX Colorspace without giving up emission material color?

Tags: color

I like that when I set a cube to have a red emission with the filmic color space that the red cube also looks red and the whole light it emits is red as well.

The new AgX color space allows a higher color spectrum, which is nice for more detail and realism.
However, all my emission objects became very white and not their original emission color.

Is there a way to have the advantages of the AgX color spectrum with the filmic or none color emission? So I don't have to give up more color detail and also don't have to give up my emission colors.

In other terms:

With AgX:

[image]

Without AgX:

[image]

Is there a way to have the true red within AgX?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/

Comment: @DuarteFarrajotaRamos thank you. works perfectly