# Change world strength without affecting color?

Tags: color, world

I am using the default world (Background). I need to change the world strength but mantain its color. Is it possible?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the *Shader Editor > World*, mix the *Background* node with another one in a *Shader > Mix Shader* and use an *Input > Light Path (Is Camera Ray* output) as factor:

[image]

If you want to keep the same color but just change the *Strength*, plug an *Input > RGB* (or *Environment Texture* nodes) into 2 *Background* nodes:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just adjust the strength:

[image]

It depends on the whole scene how it changes the color of the lighting though. If you have other lights in the scene that are different color, when you lower the strength of your world background, they start contributing more to the overall lighting so you could adjust them accordingly until you get the same colors, or you could adjust your shaders as well.

You can take a screenshot of your desired colors and then load it into your scene on a plane with shadeless material(emission shader) so you can compare the results you get to your desired result directly while adjusting other lights or your shaders. Or just have it on screen in something like [PureRef](https://www.pureref.com/).

Hue/Saturation/Value node is useful for changing color(as you can see I happen to use it as well in the scene I happen to work on at the time to adjust HDRI lighting color) or it's also possible to use Color Mix node in multiply mode - that might sometimes be convenient, but it's just a suggestion and there are many ways to manipulate colors of shaders(including shaders used for lights).

Comment: I did assume we are talking about color specifically (meaning the hue of the light). Only seeing the answer Moonboots provided,  I realize you might have meant that you want to preserve how the background looks to the camera(meaning color and brightness).