How to preserve color saturation with high transmission BSDF (Cycles)
I am using a Principled BSDF to have some transmission on a pane. However, the transmission causes the colors to lose a lot of saturation.
The colors are I'm interested in (this uses no transmission).

As I increase the transmission, I lose a lot of saturation from the color palette. Is there a way to enable transmission such that I do not lighten the image. (Cycles)


https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/53359/how-do-you-make-an-image-emission-without-washing-out-the-image https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58272/making-an-emission-shader-emit-a-different-colour-of-light-than-the-colour-assig
